# How to know if some website is Servlet/JSP based?

Tags: java, php, jsp, servlets, web

If there is a way we can know if some website is Servlet/JSP based or some other technology like by  checking source code or something like that?

Comment: Nope. The server can choose to identify itself as JSP or anything it wants. There's no way to be sure just by looking at the headers or anything in the  html source.

Comment: There's a great Google Chrome plugin called Appspector that tells a lot about the tech behind a site. Never seen JSP but it tells if a site runs php/drupal etc so it could maybe help you? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appspector/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae?hl=en

Comment: Appspector! Gotta try this :)

Answer (score 1):

Since JSP compiles and creates a completely normal HTML file there is no way of knowing this unless the server chooses to identify itself.

Comment: How does **a server chooses to identify itself** ?

Comment: That would be that the developer purposely mentions in the HTML that the page is generated using JSP for example.

You generally don't want to let others know what you are using because it makes it easier for hackers to target your server.

Comment: The response header `Server` by default has server detail.  If this has a server name known for being a Servlet container, then the application is Servlet based, but not specifically JSP based as servlet can use different templating engines.

Answer (score 1):

Find  in your Response Header.

- Glash Fish = `Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1`
- Tomcat = `Server:    Apache-Coyote/1.1`

Coyote is a Connector component for Tomcat that supports the HTTP 1.1 protocol as a web server. This allows Catalina, nominally a Java Servlet or JSP container, to also act as a plain web server that serves local files as HTTP documents.

So if you find this in the header, the application is in Java Web application using tomcat as a server.